# SoapFault exception: [500]

Tags: php, exception, soap

I am all new to soap and i have only a little idea as to what im doing. Any attempts to fix the issue or find a description as to whats goin on have been fruitless. I can't seem to get rid of a constant nagging exception:

```
SoapFault exception: [500] Username required in path\index.php:38<br />
Stack trace:<br />
#0 path\index.php(38): SoapClient->__soapCall('createPlayer', Array)<br />
#1 {main}
```

The wsdl is here - http://www.laifacai.com/soap/gameprovider?wsdl

And this is in my php.

```
$soap_options = array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 1 );
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.laifacai.com/soap/gameprovider?wsdl", array( 'login' => "user", 'password' => "pass"));

var_dump ($client->__getFunctions ());

if (!class_exists('SoapClient')){

        die ("You haven't installed the PHP-Soap module.");

} else {

    try {

        $res = $client->__soapCall('createPlayer', array('username'=>'mstest1', 'password'=>'12345678')));

    } catch (SOAPFault $f) {

        echo "<pre>" . $f . "</pre>"; 

    }

}
```

Basicaly, i have a few methods on the wsld that i would like to handle. I though that createPlayer would be the easiest one and i could get on from there based on what i've learned, but i can't get it right, i don't know whats wrong and i can't find it out. It doesent matter if i pass an empty array or a full one, allways the same "Username requiered".

Edit: Wsld link edited

Comment: can you add the WSDL in your question, the link you've given doesn't give out the WSDL.

Comment: Edited, souhld work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "Username required", so try providing it. Currently you're only providing `username` (note the lower caps). SOAP is case sensitive.

Also, I think your

```
$res = $client->__soapCall('createPlayer',
    array('username'=>'mstest1', 'password'=>'12345678')));
```

should be

```
$SoapCallParameters = array('username'=>'mstest1', 'password'=>'12345678');
$res = $client->__soapCall('createPlayer',
    array('parameters'=>$SoapCallParameters));
```

---

According to your WSDL documentation, you should supply

```
array(
   'agentid'
   'username'
   'password'
   'currencycode'
   'countrycode'
   'nickname'
   'fname'
   'lname'
)
```

for createPlayer, so just username and password is not enough.

Comment: @MSthunder1 you did the parameters change too?

Comment: Yes but they arent set as required so it works with just username and password.